ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Roles' - attempted relative import beyond top-level package
I am trying to organize my application so other developers can build off of it. When I try to test my application I keep getting the attempted relative import beyond top-level package error. I started with a mvc template and everything was working until I tried to import my controller files that I made to the main app.py file. As I am typing this I found the solution and figured out I worded the import incorrectly. However now when I try to run flask run I get the error ModuleNotFound even though vs code recognizes the file.
Here is the folder directory
Here is the import section of the app.py file
I tried to run the flask run command in bash to start a local server so I can test the functions out. But I get the No module name 'Roles' error.

I would suggest to avoid images of code and file structure. Instead, text is much easier to reproduce. Please, check How do I ask a good question?.

Since app.py lives inside the backend folder, the relative imports of controllers should be:
from .roles.controllers import <functions>
from .users.controllers import <functions>

I have checked it running
cd backend
flask run

with the following layout:
└── backend
    ├── app.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── roles
    │   ├── controllers.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── users
        ├── controllers.py
        └── __init__.py


Thank you and I will do that moving forward
